# Why do these 2 "equivalent" queries return different numbers of rows?

Tags: sql

Maybe I've been looking at this too long--but can someone please help me see why these two queries, which are supposed to return the same thing, return different numbers of rows?

```
select ip.* 
from invoice_payment ip
inner join invoice_item II on ii.invoice_item_uuid = ip.invoice_item_uuid
inner join service_delivery sd on sd.service_delivery_uuid = ii.service_delivery_uuid
inner join #Affected on #Affected.service_delivery_uuid = sd.service_delivery_uuid


select * 
from invoice_payment ip
where ip.invoice_item_uuid in (
  select ii.invoice_item_uuid from invoice_item ii
  where ii.service_delivery_uuid in (
    select service_delivery_uuid from #Affected)
)
```

Thank you!

Comment: They are not equivalent queries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one returns a product:

```
IP x II x sd x #Affected
```

The product is then limited by the `on` conditions.  But if any condition matches multiple rows, you'll end up with more rows than there are in the `IP` table.

The second query returns rows in IP matching a certain condition.  The second query can never return more rows than there are in IP.

Comment: Thank you, Andomar.  So are you saying that the 2nd one is more accurate?  I'll be turning this Select into a Delete, so it's important that I get the correct result.

Comment: Yeah, the second would more accurately capture a delete.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the tables invoice_item, service_delivery, or #Affected contains more than one record corresponding to the table to which it's JOINed, then this will increase the number of records in the result set, effectively multiplying the number of times that invoice_payment is reported.

Since it seems likely to me that an invoice_payment may correspond to more than one invoice_item, that's where I'd look first.

The two queries, by the way, are not even approximately equivalent.